# Initiatize temporary variable on the same line as if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
const exp = function (input) {
  let v;
  return (v = input.foo.bar) ? v : 'bar' 
};
```

I am wondering, if there is a way to put the temporary variable on the same line, something like this:

```
const exp = function (input) {
  return let v, (v = input.foo.bar) ? v : 'bar' 
};
```

that's not valid syntax tho. JS runtime says "cannot find name v".

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to do `v.foo` if `v` is uninitialized?

Comment: consider using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get), e.g. `return _.get(v, 'foo', 'bar');`

Comment: If `v` will be undefined initially, referencing `v.foo` while attempting to assign to `v` will surely throw an error. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do with your initial code?

Comment: whoops I made a mistake in the OP, forgot something, updated it

Comment: @ic3b3rg yeah lodash's functionality might be best option here, now that I fixed the OP, please add an answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get), e.g. `return _.get(input, 'foo.bar', 'bar');`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to require a library for something so simple - the conditional operator will resolve the first expression if the condition is falsey, and to the second expression otherwise, so why not just use `||`, which will do the same thing, and just reference the `input` parameter without declaring an unnecessary additional variable?

```
const exp = input => input.foo.bar || 'bar';
```

Or, even more tersely, with destructuring, though it's a bit less readable:

```
const exp = ({foo:{bar}}) => bar || 'bar';
```

Comment: "obviously" the OP was a simplification of the situation. here is the real scenario: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/76224cc951c59c664a11b14d48c411aa

Comment: Next time I will just use the real code lol, this didn't go as planned haha

Comment: Yeah that was my fault, lesson learned, thanks tho, you got an upvote from me just now

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
const exp = (input) => (v = input.foo.bar) ? v : 'bar'
```

It makes none sense to call let in function. If you call it inside, it would be to init it. so you do not need to check if it is equal to something.
In your case, const v should be outside your function and have a value.

Comment: yeah thanks, I made an update to the OP, not a big change, but please update your answer accordingly, the question will make more sense now.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my answer. You should populate variable 'v'. If 'v' exists outside the function, you do not need to call 'let v'. And if v does not exists, then call it inside with 'const v', but then you do not need to check its value, as it would be empty.

Comment: I think your solution will make v a global variable

Answer (score 0):

This was a really dumb question on my part, I have solved this little riddle before, but it wasn't coming to me. Probably the best way to do this is something simple like:

```
const exp = function (input) {
  let v = input.foo && input.foo.bar;
  return v || 'bar' 
};
```